# how to define an "empty" async generator in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to define an "empty" async generator i.e. one that does not generate any values. Since the definition of an async generator is an async function containing a yield statement, this is what I came up with:

```
async def _empty_async_generator() -> AsyncGenerator[str, None]:
    if False:
        yield ""
```

Is that the best that can be done in python 3.10? Is there a library function for creating empty async generators?

Comment: `if False: yield ""` can't be replaced with `pass`?

Comment: @Ouroborus no, because it needs `yield` in the function definition to be a generator.

Comment: I think `yield from ()`, instead of `if False: yield ""`, is more directly an empty generator. But it doesn't seem like it gets easier than that.

Comment: Another solution is `class empty_async_iterator:def __aiter__(self):return self def __anext__(self):raise StopAsyncIteration`, but I like the `yield from` solution in your previous comment more.

Comment: You could use [`asyncstdlib.itertools`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/source/api/itertools.html)

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip, but I couldn't find anything there that fits

Comment: @Ouroborus `yield from` is not allowed in an async function